# Android FCM Push notification is NOT delivered

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, push

I sent the following notification json request to FCM gateway:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

And the following is the json request:

```
{ "data": {"body": "Nice to meet you!"},"to" : "dWgg2uGMlrs:APA91bFWhoMvV2WIZrYlENUqHzP0J2fXTuBGo-FiFd-YwGUT6vqyTjeGiOi28rOnU6MQggDwziQ7Xwg4mw6Fbnjo4-OqfOKsfw1M4E6w2rRxc0yQyGbKhQEGpIGC2eIc2CACYrEudsxz","priority" : "high"}
```

And the following is FCM gateway response

```
{"multicast_id":7757558437981419128,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1489893859089718%f58ec05df9fd7ecd"}]}
```

However, my my phone is not able to receive the notification. If I use the exact same device token `dWgg2uGMlrs:APA91bFWhoMvV2WIZrYlENUqHzP0J2fXTuBGo-FiFd-YwGUT6vqyTjeGiOi28rOnU6MQggDwziQ7Xwg4mw6Fbnjo4-OqfOKsfw1M4E6w2rRxc0yQyGbKhQEGpIGC2eIc2CACYrEudsxz` and send notification in FCM web console https://console.firebase.google.com
I am able to receive the notification.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. The request and response are totally valid. There was a bug in my android app. Issue closed.